# Java new certificate chain ,reference to Certificate is ambiguous

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I want to add a key to a keystore. The keystore's method `setKeyEntry` wants a `Certificate` chain for the parameter. I created the `Certificate` chain like this:

```
Certificate[] certChain = new Certificate[1];
```

However, I get the error:

> "reference to Certificate is ambiguous both class
>   org.bouncy.asn1.x.508.Certificate in org.bouncycastle.asn.1.x509 and
>   interface java.security.Certificate in java.security match".

In my google search, I can find general help for ambiguous methods that doesn't help with my problem. What can I do to solve the problem at hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error has stated there's ambiguity with other classes and interfaces. [`setKeyEntry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#setKeyEntry(java.lang.String,%20byte[],%20java.security.cert.Certificate[])) takes a `Certificate` argument which is located at *java.security.cert.Certificate*. Therefore to remove the ambiguity, you can prefix it with the full package name e.g.

```
java.security.cert.Certificate[] certChain = new java.security.cert.Certificate[1];
```